# How do I use Octokit to turn on Github Pages for a repo?

Tags: github-api, octokit

I have a Ruby program that makes a new repo for a user using Octokit. I would also like to enable Github Pages for the repo from my program, but I can't figure out if that is possible. The [Pages API](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Pages.html) seems to assume pages are already enabled.

Comment: Apparently others have hit this roadblock as well: https://apievangelist.com/2018/04/16/if-github-pages-could-be-turned-on-by-default-i-could-provide-a-run-on-github-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific API to call when "enabling" the GitHub page feature.
As described in "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)"

> If your site is a User or Organization Page that has a repository named `<username>.github.io` or `<orgname>.github.io`, you cannot publish your site's source files from different locations.
>   User and Organization Pages that have this type of repository name are only published from the `master` branch.

For other project repos, the following settings needs to be set manually first:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/none-source-setting.png]